# How to properly map an SSM parameter store StringList to a Lambda VpcConfig section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm new to Cloudformation (coming from Terraform). I have a parameter in SSM

```
Key: /qa0/myService/lambda/subnetIds
Value: subnet-1234abcd, subnet-5678abcd
Type: StringList
```

I want to [dynamically reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) this parameter in the [VpcConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-vpcconfig.html) section of a Lambda in a Cloudformation template, but I'm not getting something right. I've tried a bunch of different things. Also, I'm using a `StackEnv` parameter to allow for reuse through multiple environments, so this parameter will be populated as qa0, qa1, etc.

---

```
VpcConfig:
    SecurityGroupIds: !Ref VpcSecurityGroupIds
    SubnetIds: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${StackEnv}/myService/lambda/subnetIds:1}}'
```

Result: "Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String"

---

```
VpcConfig:
    SecurityGroupIds: !Ref VpcSecurityGroupIds
    SubnetIds: [!Split [",", !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${StackEnv}/myService/lambda/subnetIds:1}}']]
```

Result: "The subnet ID 'subnet-1234abcd,subnet-5678abcd' does not exist". For some reason it's not splitting the StringList here.

edit: taking Split out of the array here (`SubnetIds: !Split [ ",", !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${StackEnv}/myService/lambda/subnetIds:1}}']`) as 404 suggested in the comments gets me the same result.

---

If I try [defining the SSM parameter as a Cloudformation template parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types) (`AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<List<String>>`), I get stuck because I need the Default to substitute in `StackEnv` and not be a static string, which isn't supported. The template complains that Default must be a string.

---

I've tried various versions of nesting the dynamic lookup result in square brackets, with no luck:

`SubnetIds: [ !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${StackEnv}/myService/lambda/subnetIds:1}}' ]`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Split` returns an array, so don't put it in an array: `SubnetIds: [!Split` -> `SubnetIds: !Split`

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter. Edited my question to cover `!Split` outside of an array.

Answer (score 6):

I confirmed with AWS official support - CloudFormation is "executing the intrinsic functions before the inline references here, which is a buggy behavior from CloudFormation." (their words) To be clear, the buggy behavior is 100% consistent for me and this SubnetIds field.