# How to reference AWS SSM Parameter in Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloud Formation template for a lambda function. The function requires a VPC. I have 2 SSM Parameters for Security Group and Subnets.

```
Name: platform_security_group
Type: String
Value: sg-mySecurityGroupID
Name: platform_subnets
Type: String
Value: subnet-mySubnetID1,subnet-mySubnetID2
```

The parameter for Subnet has 2 comma separated values.
I use this in my template -

```
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:        
          - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:platform_security_group:3}}'
        SubnetIds:
          - !Split [",", !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:platform_subnets:3}}']
```

But its not working and gives me this error -

```
Properties validation failed for resource myFunction with message: #/VpcConfig/SubnetIds/0: expected type: String, found: JSONArray
```

Note: I have also tried changing the Type of Parameter platform_subnets to StringList but the error is still same!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with `SubnetIds: !Split [",", !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:platform_subnets:3}}']`?

Comment: I have tried this but the error remains same!

Comment: Looks like the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57970690/12326605

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
VpcConfig:
  SecurityGroupIds:        
    - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:platform_security_group:3}}'
  SubnetIds:
    - Fn::Split:
      - ","
      - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:platform_subnets:3}}'
```

Comment: I just tried it but getting the same error!
`Properties validation failed for resource myFunction with message: #/VpcConfig/SubnetIds/0: expected type: String, found: JSONArray`
I tried with the Type of parameter platform_subnets with both String and StringList.

Comment: Can you share exactly what the subnets look like stored?

Comment: subnet-0e13c119628c2c1b7,subnet-053d6263987v71984

Comment: what should be the ideal Type for the Parameter? String or StringList?

Comment: It should be a string. Are you certain your string doesn't contain `[]`?

Comment: no, it does not contain `[]`
This is how it is - `subnet-0e13c119628c2c1b7,subnet-053d6263987v71984`